# CSS Table - Right side doesn't fit in the browser

Tags: asp.net, css, xhtml

I've been working on our company website this morning and I've hit a bit of a problem.  I have the page formatted into two cells, one on the right and one on the left.  The one on the right contains an image which is around 790 pixels wide.  When I shrink the browser window to the point to where it will no longer fit, the whole cell jumps below the first cell.  How can I prevent this from happening?

Code...

xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>
Test
</title>
<link href="StyleSheet1.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="default.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTg2ODI4NzA2OWQYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgEFCUNoZWNrQm94MU+tEbqmFYLAUCuNpKlG5GJdxlTP" />
</div>

<div>

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBwKUzskuAuzRsusGAoznisYGAuzR9tkMAuzRirUFAoLk17sJArursYYIEh1rVMqwd3ohPqFy9J1P74IvCz4=" />
</div>
<div style = "padding-left:15%;">
<div class = "header">
    <img src="images/logoclr.bmp" style="height:56px;width:253px;border-width:0px;" />
    <input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" style="width:414px;" />
    <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Search" id="Button1" />
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="loginSide">
    <div class = "internalBox">
    Log On To Invoice Viewer
    </div>
    <br />
    <span>Login ID:</span>
    <br />
    <input name="TextBox2" type="text" id="TextBox2" />
    *<br />
    <br />
    <span id="Label1">Password</span>
    <br />
    <input name="TextBox3" type="text" id="TextBox3" />
    *<br />
    <br />
    <input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" />
    Remember my Login ID<br />
    <br />
    <div style="padding-left:20px;"><input type="submit" name="Button2" value="Login" id="Button2" /></div>
    <br />
</div>
<div class = "imageSide">
    <img src="images/1_back11.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" />
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body 
{
background-color:rgb(227,227,225);
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:.8em;
margin-left:auto;
}

.loginSide
{
float:left;
border-width:1px;
border-right:0px;
border-color:rgb(186,107,255);
border-style:solid;
width:275px;
height:292px;
padding:10px;
background-color:rgb(223,232,237);
}

.imageSide
{
border-width:1px;
border-color:rgb(186,107,255);
border-style:solid;
width:792px;
padding:10px;
background-color:rgb(223,232,237);
float:left;

}

.internalBox
{
padding-left:50px;
padding-right:50px;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
background-color:rgb(54,113,109);
color:White;
}
```

Comment: "The one on the left contains an image..." I guess you mean the one on the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I wrapped the image in this div:

```
<div style = "overflow: hidden;">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set an id to the div that wraps everything (e.g. `<div id="wrapper" style="padding-left:15%;">`) and create a CSS selector for it where you specify a minimum width:

```css
#wrapper {
    min-width: 900px;
}
```

The width you should choose according to the minimum width where the image div *doesn't* wrap. Of course, now that you have a selector for the wrapper, you could move the `padding-left` into the CSS as well instead of having it inline.

[Here's and example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZNkE/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the width of your cells dynamic. If you use a percentage instead of a fixed width it will automatically adjust to the window size.

```
.imageSide
{
border-width:1px;
border-color:rgb(186,107,255);
border-style:solid;
width:70%;
padding:10px;
background-color:rgb(223,232,237);
float:left;

}

.loginSide
{
float:left;
border-width:1px;
border-right:0px;
border-color:rgb(186,107,255);
border-style:solid;
width:30%;
height:292px;
padding:10px;
background-color:rgb(223,232,237);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Don't provide the `width` of `imageSide` because it must adjust with remaining width of browser window while `loginSide` must stick to its own *solid* width.

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVMvf/).

One more thing, you are using `float: left` in both `loginSide` and `imageSide`, just use it at `loginSide`, `imageSide` will than adjust automatically.

Here is the *updated* [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVMvf/1/).

And, finally if you want your own code without any much altration, i got this also for you. :)

Here is the your [*second updated* fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVMvf/2/) with `imageSide` `width:792px` also..

Cheers.. :)